# Open website in a new window javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to open my website in a new fullscreen window which does not have back, forward and refresh buttons to give it a webApp look. I am able to achieve it with the below code:

```
function open_window ()
    {   
        var w = window.location.href

        var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
        // mobile device detection
        if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))){
            isMobile = true;
        }
        if(isMobile === false){

            try {
                mywindow=window.open(w,"ABC",'height=heigth,width=width,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,directories=0');
                mywindow.window.moveTo(0,0);
                mywindow.window.resizeTo(window.screen.availWidth,window.screen.availHeight);
            }
            catch(e){   return false;   }
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onpaint = open_window();
```

The problem is that the parent window also loads the website. how to stop the parent window from loading the website? i have searched the web but no luck. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please. Don't. Do. That. If I visited a site, and it did that, it would go on my blacklist ***instantly***. I'm shocked it works, and looking forward to browser vendors fixing that bug.

Comment: i want to restrict the user from using back and forward buttons because it can cause problems in the backend, thats why i am opening it in a new popup window with browser back and forwards buttons are hidden

Comment: If going forwards and backwards through your application can negatively impact your back-end you need to fix your back-end. This is an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem for sure.

Comment: @arsinawaz: Then fix the backend. Meanwhile, hiding the buttons only hides the buttons. Alt+Left and Alt+Right still work. But if you absolutely **must** do this, at least warn the user, and do it on click. Don't just make it happen without warning, that's unacceptable web behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the window.open function to open the website new window.
The code below shows positioning the popup at a desired location.

```
function mypopup()
{
    mywindow = window.open("http://jsc.simfatic-solutions.com", "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=100,height=100");
    mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: i am already able to open the window with my code but the problem is that the parent window is also loading the website. how to stop the parent window from loading it? thanks